# How to do taylor expansion of metric tensor to get Lagrangian for first Post-Newtonian order?

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, black-holes, metric-tensor, post-newtonian

For the two-body compact object system how to write Lagrangian after obtaining first post-Newtonian metric tensor(just gravitational field)? Considering the perturbation in the metric as $$gαβ=ηαβ+hαβ, \qquad   |hαβ|≪1.$$ Basically what is the method to obtain the Lagrangian for a perturbated metric tensor?
(we write lagrangian as $$ L= \int ds = \int \sqrt(g_{αβ} dx^α dx^β) $$ )
Because if we write the 'ds' as the expansion of perturbation metric tensor we get the term which doesn't match with EIH Lagrangian. Why so? That is how to get Lagrangian after getting $$ \sqrt(g_{αβ} dx^α dx^β)$$ How to expand this term? Because I get miss match in solution.
$$ds^{2}=c^{2}(1+\frac{2GM}{c^{2}}-\frac{2 U^2}{c^{2}}+\frac{3 U(v^{i})^{2}}{c^{2}})+\frac{8Uv^{i}}{c^{2}}+\frac{\partial U}{c^{2}}\delta_{ij}v^{i}v^{i}+\delta_{ij}(v^{i}v^{j})$$
I am getting extra terms and even that do we consider $\int ds^2/c^2$ as Lagrangian??

Comment: In MathJax, you can make subscripts with an underscore. For example, `$g_{\alpha\beta}$` gives $g_{\alpha\beta}$.